# Module build failed for react tips 'Unknown helper getPrototypeOf'

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I use babel to complain when compiling a component that inherits a react component, I didn't check for syntax errors

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>
                hello world!
            </h1>
        )
    }
}
ReactDom.render(
    <Hello/>,
    document.getElementById('index')
);
```

Running tips

```
ERROR in ./app/src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
ReferenceError: Unknown helper getPrototypeOf
```

My operating system is windows 10

node version 10.1.0

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0"
  }
}
```

**Problem solved, use @babel/core instead of babel-core**

Comment: Not about question, but may be usefull- you use "counter" component, but where it is imported or declared?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the component name should be Hello instead of Counter, but the error is still the same